MatchThem and Mixed-Effects Logistic Regression in R
MatchThem and Logistic Regression in R
I am conducting a non-randomized study to evaluate the differences in complication rates between two treatments. The observed complication rates are significantly different between the two groups (22% vs. 50%). To account for potential confounders, I plan to use a binomial logistic regression model. Given the relatively small sample size (130 patients, split 53 vs. 77), and the presence of 7 missing values in one of my covariates (comorbidities), I opted to impute the missing data using the MICE (Multiple Imputation by Chained Equations) method to avoid losing these patients. Below the code:
# Impute missing values
new_df_imputed <- mice(selected_data, m = 5, maxit = 50, method = "pmm", seed = 123)

Next, I performed propensity score matching (PSM) using the MatchThem package:
# Perform matching in each imputed dataset
m.out_model1 <- matchthem(Treatment_type_tumor_near_gallbladder ~ age + sex + bmi + ASA + comorbidities + Systemic_treatment_prior_local_treatment + Segments_treated_per_session + Metastasis_size_at_treatment_mm + min_distance_gallblad_mm + stage, 
data = new_df_imputed, 
method = "nearest", 
distance = "logit",
replace = TRUE,
ratio = 3,
caliper = 0.2) 

The matching process achieved good balance with acceptable results:
Balance tally for mean differences
                   count
Balanced, <0.1        16
Not Balanced, >0.1     2

Variable with the greatest mean difference
                     Variable Max.Diff.Adj        M.Threshold
 Segments_treated_per_session       0.1602 Not Balanced, >0.1

Average sample sizes across imputations
                         0    1
All                  53.   77. 
Matched (ESS)        29.34 67.8
Matched (Unweighted) 46.8  67.8
Unmatched             6.2   9.2

After that, I implemented a multivariate analysis using the following code:
results <- with(m.out_model1, svyglm(complications ~ Treatment_type_tumor_near_gallbladder + age + sex + bmi + ASA + comorbidities + Systemic_treatment_prior_local_treatment + Segments_treated_per_session + Metastasis_size_at_treatment_mm + min_distance_gallblad_mm + stage,
family = quasibinomial()))

output <- pool(results, dfcom = NULL)

summary(output, exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE) %>%     
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, digits = 3))

Question 1:
Does the svyglm function automatically account for the fact that I matched with replacement and used a ratio of 3:1?
Question 2:
Is it possible to perform a backward elimination process on the summary of the model? Does it make sense?
Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

It depends on what you mean by "account for". It automatically incorporates the matching weights and computes a robust standard error. If that is enough to "account for" the matched nature of the data, then yes. Not everyone agrees that that is enough. For example, some argue you should bootstrap, some argue bootstrapping is invalid, some argue you need to account for both the repeated use of controls and the matched nature of the data, some argue you need to use a special standard error designed specifically for matching with replacement. There is no consensus yet and the use of matching with replacement with multiply imputed data is not well understood. Many of the better-studied methods of adjusting inferences for matching with replacement are not easily implemented in current technology.
Do not use backward elimination. Just interpret the effect estimate using marginaleffects::avg_comparisons(). You should not be interpreting the outcome model at all. You should not be performing model selection after estimating the treatment effect. There is no benefit to model selection except a slight gain in precision (in theory), though the uncertainty associated with the model selection itself could negate that benefit. Why do you want to use backward selection or any model selection at all? The goal is not to find a parsimonious or generalizable model but rather to estimate a treatment effect precisely and without bias.
You mention "mixed effects logistic regression" in the title but I don't see such a model. You also mention fitting a multivariate model, but I only see a univariate model (one outcome with multiple predictors); "multivariate" means multiple outcomes.

Thank you for your response. You are correct—it was a multivariable regression, not multivariate. Since the outcome “complications” is computed on a session basis (with some patients treated more than once, N = 112 patients and N = 130 sessions), I intended to use mixed-effects logistic regression. I initially thought that svyglm was appropriate, but I now realize that it was not the correct choice. Thank you!
